# The medians drawn to the given sides intersect at a right angle.What are the conditions for the triangle to exist?

Tags: geometry

Given two sides $a$ and $b$ of a triangle,and it is known that the medians drawn to the given sides intersect at a right angle.What are the conditions for the triangle to exist?

---

In the triangle $ABC$,let $AB=c,BC=a,AC=b$and let medians $AD$ and $BE$ intersect at a point $O$.
First i found $c$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.Let $OD=x$,so $AO=2x$ and let $OE=y$,so $BO=2y$
In triangle $AOE$,
$4x^2+y^2=\frac{b^2}{4}$
In triangle $AOB$,
$4x^2+4y^2=c^2$
In triangle $BOD$,
$4y^2+x^2=\frac{a^2}{4}$
Eliminating $x$ and $y$,we obtain $c^2=\frac{a^2-b^2}{5}$
But i am stuck here.I dont know how to proceed further to find the conditions for existence of triangle.
The answer given is $\frac{1}{2}<\frac{a}{b}<2$.Please help me.

Comment: Try to use the conditions $b<a+c$ and $a<b+c$ that every triangle must satisfy.

Comment: I have tried these conditions but not successful.

Comment: Recheck you calculation: you equations gives $c^2=\frac{a^2+b^2}{5}$. Then use the inequality I wrote and you should get the result.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but you can use [Stewart's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem) to find the length of the median.

Comment: @mrprottolo,yes my $c^2$ should be $\frac{a^2+b^2}{5}$ and then $a-b<c<a+b\implies(a-b)^2<c^2<(a+b)^2$ is working.Thank you very much.

Comment: Let the median from *A* of side $a=BC$ be perpendicular on the median from *B* of side $b=AC$. Then *C* describes a circle centered in the middle of side $c=AB,$ whose diameter is thrice the size of side $c=AB$.